# How to pass ng-click executable action (&) in variable into directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

HTML view with directive:

```
<div click aaa="aaa()" action="action"></div>
```

Controller: I like to pass function bbb() in $scope.action:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.aaa = function () { alert('aaa'); }
    $scope.bbb = function () { alert('bbb'); }

    $scope.action = 'bbb()';
});
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('click', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            aaa: '&',
            action: '&'
        },
        template: 
            '<button ng-click="aaa()">show aaa (work ok)</button>' +
            '<button ng-click="action">show bbb (not work)</button>' +
            '<br>How to pass ng-click action in variable into directive?'
    }
});
```

I don't know how to evaluate `action` to be replaced with `bbb()`.

here is plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/d8DtsNARKPPJwk2SO2WJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$scope.action` needs to be a pointer to `$scope.bbb` and not just a string that refers to it loosely.  `"bbb()` in the controller means nothing, while `$scope.bbb()` is what you created and need to use.  When you're in HTML, `$scope` is implied, which is why you can get away with simply writing `aaa()`.

In your template and your HTML, you also need to call `action`, just as you are calling `aaa`.

http://jsfiddle.net/DFcJf/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div click aaa="aaa()" action="action()"></div>

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('click', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            aaa: '&',
            action: '&'
        },
        template: 
            '<button ng-click="aaa()">show aaa (work ok)</button>' +
            '<button ng-click="action()">show bbb (not work)</button>' +
            '<br>How to pass ng-click action in variable into directive?'
    }
});
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.aaa = function () { alert('aaa'); }
    $scope.bbb = function () { alert('bbb'); }

    $scope.action = $scope.bbb;
});
```