# Pass an array of objects with function to directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a directive that dynamically adds buttons to a `div`.
To pass the buttons, I created a `json` that hold the text, class, and action of the button, but the function does not fire on click. what am I doing wrong?

Directive template:

```
<div>
    <button ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-class="button.class" ng-click="button.action">
        {{ text }}
    </button>
</div>
```

Directive:
app

```
.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            buttons: '=buttons'
        },
        templateUrl: "url/to/template"
    }
});
```

index.html:

```
<my-directive buttons="[
        {
            action: scopeFunction,
            test: 'my text',
            class: 'my-class'
        }
    ]"></my-directive>
```

**Edit**: the problem is not with the camel casing as people here suggested. I am using another name and the directive works. Only the button action does not fire.

**Edit 2**: Created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/umkzjn42/1/

Comment: Can provide jsffidle/plunker link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234766/how-to-pass-ng-click-executable-action-in-variable-into-directive

Comment: @VaibhavShah working on it

Comment: @Algosub already created jsfiddle, see my answer below :)  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eu1356x8/)

Comment: @Algosub updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Give Name to the Directive like **myDirective**(camelCase) in place of **my-directive**

```
.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            buttons: '=buttons'
        },
        templateUrl: "url/to/template"
    }
});
```

and then use it as 'my-directive'

```
<my-directive buttons="[
        {
            action: scopeFunction(),
            test: 'my text',
            class: 'my-class'
        }
    ]"></my-directive>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must write directive with camel-case

```
.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            buttons: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "url/to/template"
    }
});
```

and then you can use it as

```
<my-directive buttons="[
    {
        action: scopeFunction(),
        test: 'my text',
        class: 'my-class'
    }
]"></my-directive>
```

you can read about  [directive in angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 0):

when we declare directive, we need to define name in camel-case.

**HTML**

```
<my-directive>
```

**JS**

```
.directive("myDirective", function() {}
```

other mistake in your `JSON`
you are using `text` in HTML template, and passing `test` in directive

another problem with in your HTML template, you are passing function reference instead **calling the function**. use `ng-click="button.action()"` instead `ng-click="button.action"`

see your [working directive here](https://jsfiddle.net/eu1356x8/1/)

Comment: My problem is that the functions do not fire... the directive shows up with no problem

Answer (score -1):

```
<my-directive buttons="[
        {
            action: scopeFunction(),
            test: 'my text',
            class: 'my-class'
        }
    ]"></my-directive>
```

I think you are missing parenthesis for function calling in defining your action. Hope that solves the issue